# Global Dictionary Object Accessible from a Userform

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I declared a public global dictionary object in a regular module as follows:

```
Public dicModels As Scripting.Dictionary  'Microsoft Scripting Runtime has been added as a reference
```

I have the following Callback:

```
Sub CreatePPT_OnAction(control As IRibbonControl)
    Call CurrentBooks
    Dim frmPPT_Slide As FPowerPoint
    Set frmPPT_Slide = New FPowerPoint
    frmPPT_Slide.Show
    Set frmPPT_Slide = Nothing
End Sub
```

Here is my subroutine for the call procedure:

```
Sub CurrentBooks()
    Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim vObject As Variant

    If Not dicModels Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set dicModels = New Dictionary
    For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        For Each vObject In wks.ListObjects
            If Left(vObject.Name, 3) = "TM_" Then
            dicModels.Add Key:=vObject.Name, Item:=Right(vObject.Name, Len(vObject.Name) - InStr(1, vObject.Name, "_"))
            End If
        Next vObject
    Next wks

End Sub
```

Here is my initialize Event in the Userform (iCounter is a module level variable declared as private):

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.Caption = "Main Tracking Model"
    Me.lblModel.Caption = "Choose a model to be reflected on the PPT slide."
    For iCounter = 0 To dicModels.Count  '<< ERROR!!!!!
        Me.lstModels.AddItem dicModels.Items(iCounter)
    Next iCounter
End Sub
```

I am trying to create a global dictionary object to be accessible from the userform class. Although I have it declared public at the module level  I still get `Object variable or With block variable not set`. I must be misunderstanding or overlooking something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: In `CurrentBooks` you are corectly using `Set dicModels = New Dictionary`. The code as it is here in the question should work, or at least the `dicModels` should not be `Nothing`. Colud it be that something happens which we don't see here and which sets the dic. to `Nothing`? And one question: the code of `UserForm_Initialize` belongs to the `FPowerPoint` right?

Comment: @dee Yes, the code in `UserForm_Initialize` belongs to `FPowerPoint`. Clearly, something is setting the dic object to `Nothing`. Otherwise, something is wrong with my scope. I'll do more debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Write as follows:

```
Public dicModels As New Scripting.Dictionary
```

This both declares the variable, and initializes it to a new `Dictionary`.

---

This initialization can be done together with the declaration. If the initialization is more complex, then you're probably better off not declaring the variable public, but rather have a public function that returns the value of the variable, and carries out any initialization if needed:

```
Dim m_dicModels As Scripting.Dictionary

Public Function dicModels() As Scripting.Dictionary
    If m_dicModels Is Nothing Then
        Set m_dicModels = New Scripting.Dictionary
        m_dicModels.CompareMode = TextCompare
    End If
    Set dicModels = m_dicModels
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but I can't get it to work. When the userform is initialized I can't access the `count` property of the `dictionary` object. The dictionary is not `nothing`. Therefore, why can't I access any of its members from the userform initialize event?